# What is the whole purpose of doing componendo and Dividendo

Tags: ratio

Why do we do that?? 
[Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/) is used quite often in mathematics but I cannot figure out the reason for which we do that.

Comment: Actually, it is used very rarely, mostly in elementary texts. Usually people simply divide by $b$ on the left and $d$ on the right, and then replace $\frac{a}{b}$ by $\frac{c}{d}$ without invoking any special rule.

Comment: I've never used componendo nor dividendo, and I've been doing math since the beginning of time. Are they anything like Abbott and Costello?

Comment: Never heard of it. Is it Spanish or Italian?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Using Componendo and Dividendo means substituting an equation of form $\frac ab=\frac cd$ as $\frac {a+b}{a-b}=\frac {c+d}{c-d}$ or visa-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Componendo-dividendo is a useful little trick used to simplify particular equations. It is quite unnecessary but it  does reduce the number of steps you have to perform to get your answer. It is mostly only used when the LHS is of the form $\frac {x+a}{x-a}$ and you have to solve for $x$.